# Как установить жирность для введенного текста в input? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как установить жирность для введенного текста в input? Не для placeholder,  а именно для текста, который впишет пользователь. Placeholder должен быть без изменений в обычном состоянии.

Comment: `input { font-weight: 800; }`

Answer (score 1):

Существует селектор ::placeholder, если устраивает [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#search=::placeholder) браузеров.

```css
input {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.moo::placeholder {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<input class="moo" placeholder="moo" value="moo"><br>
<input class="moo" placeholder="moo">
```

Или, можно записать мелкий скрипт, переключающий состояние в зависимости от текущего значения:

```js
set_input_bold_typing();

function set_input_bold_typing() {
  var inp = document.querySelectorAll(".js-typing-bold");
  
  for( var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++ ) {
    if( inp[i].value ) inp[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    
    inp[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
      this.style.fontWeight = this.value ? "bold" : "300";
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="js-typing-bold" placeholder="moo" value="moo"><br>
<input class="js-typing-bold" placeholder="moo">
```